# grep windows path in file

Tags: windows, path, grep, backslash

I am trying to verify that Windows paths are found and correct in an ini file.

but **grep "C:\temp\somefile.txt" someIniFile.ini** returns "*grep: Invalid back reference*" on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `grep -F whatever`

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I saw the -F option, but did not know what it meant.